# Accept UAC Prompt Programmatically

Tags: c#, windows-7, uac

I have a C# application that needs to run with administrative permissions. In particular, it loads at Windows 7 start-up and executes a few scripts in the background. This process is fully invisible to the user and is covered up with a background when executing. The permissions implementation is via a manifest file. Now, the problem is that I need to automate the step where UAC prompt comes up, and invisibly accept it.

How would something like that be done in C#?

Comment: The whole point of the UAC prompt to begin with is that you *can't* programatically run code as the administrator without the user very explicitly saying they trust it and want to let it run as admin.  If there was a simple way to do this then it would defeat the purpose of the feature entirely, there would be no reason to add it to begin with.  It's like asking how to unlock a door without the key, or get into a safe without the combination.  If you could, there wouldn't really be much of a point in that feature existing in the first place.

Comment: I understand, but there are always ways around things, and that is exactly what I am asking.

Comment: Exactly, my analogy intentionally went to a deeper level.  You're asking is how to break into someone's safe.  The answer is, you shouldn't, even though it's generally not literally impossible.

Comment: `It loads at Windows 7 start-up and executes a few scripts in the background` - Sounds like a completely harmless program to me ;)

Comment: The software is for a kiosk station, which needs to be as clean as possible at start-up.

Comment: Can't you just disable UAC then?

Comment: If that's the case then maybe you need to run it as a service?

Comment: Or perhaps use Group Policy and have that run the startup scripts.

Comment: The best approach is to fix your app so it does not require elevation to run. (Why does it need to run elevated?) It is not possible to bypass the UAC prompt, and this is by design. The "what if this were possible" thought experiment is helpful here--if it were possible, then that's what malware would do, and UAC would be pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you have to do is impersonate a user with administrator privileges.

Try this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/chf6fbt4.aspx

I have had success with this method before, give it a shot!